# Show the right answer when selected the right cell in the table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote a code below. What I am trying to do here is, when the three right cells are selected, it should show a message saying "Right" , if not then should say "Try again". So far my code only highlights the cells. I am wondering how do I proceed next ?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
table {
width:400px;
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
border:1px solid #000;
}
table td {border:1px solid #000;}
.bgrd {background-color:#CCCCCC;cursor:pointer;}
.bgrd_selected {background-color:#FFCC00;cursor:pointer;}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setColor(what)
{
    var thetds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for(var i = 0; i < thetds.length; i++)
    {
        if(thetds[i].className == 'bgrd_selected')
        {
            thetds[i].className = 'bgrd';
        }
    }
    what.className = 'bgrd_selected';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
Select</td>
<td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
Select</td>
<td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
Select</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
Select</td>
<td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
Select</td>
<td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
Select</td>

</tr>


<tr>
<td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
Select</td>
<td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
Select</td>
<td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
Select</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
Select</td>
<td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
Select</td>
<td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
Select</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
Select</td>
<td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
Select</td>
<td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
Select</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
Select</td>
<td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
Select</td>
<td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
Select</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
Select</td>
<td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
Select</td>
<td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
Select</td>

</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by three right cells? You have 2 rows and 3 columns. Which ones you want to be selected

Comment: Sorry. I meant The bottom three.

Comment: As these are radio buttons, you can select only one. You can not select all 3 from bottom. What you really want to do?

Comment: right. i just updated the code. Its cells now, not buttons. my bad

Comment: so since its just cells now. When a user selects three cells (last three and first three), it should show "Right" if some other cells are selected then it should show "try again"

Comment: there is no check boxes. So concurrently one cannot select three cells. Are you trying to say that any of first and last three cells? Again be and make yourself clear what are you really want to do. Then perhaps I can help.

Comment: Please look here - http://pastebin.com/NU7hwD2V . Here if A1, B2 and C3 are selected it should say "Right" . if something else then it should say try again. Sorry but i thought i will make sense better above. and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are certain correct answers, you'll need to identify each possibility uniquely. I used id tags

**HTML**

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td class="bgrd" id="A1" onclick="setColor(this)">Select</td>
    <td class="bgrd" id="A2" onclick="setColor(this)">Select</td>
    <td class="bgrd" id="A3" onclick="setColor(this)">Select</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="bgrd" id="B1" onclick="setColor(this)">Select</td>
    <td class="bgrd" id="B2" onclick="setColor(this)">Select</td>
    <td class="bgrd" id="B3" onclick="setColor(this)">Select</td>
</tr>
[ ... ]
```

Next, **the Javascript**. This needs to define your correct answers, toggle the class name of the element the user clicked, then count the number of selected element and number of correct answers that are selected. Finally, if the number selected matches the number of correct answers, they're Right!

```
var answers = ["A1","B2","C3"];

function setColor(what){
    // Toggle the class name for the selected element
    what.className = (what.className == 'bgrd' ? 'bgrd_selected' : 'bgrd');

    // Set number of correct answers and selected answers to 0
    var numCorrect = 0,
        numSelected = 0;

    // Loop all relevant elements
    var thetds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for(var i = 0; i < thetds.length; i++){
        // if an element is selected, add one to numSelected
        if(thetds[i].className == 'bgrd_selected'){
            numSelected++;
        }
    }

    // Loop all possible correct answers
    for(var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++){
        // If an answer is selected, add one to numCorrect
        if(document.getElementById(answers[i]).className == 'bgrd_selected'){
            numCorrect++;
        }
    }
    // Determine if there are the same number of numCorrect and numSelected as there are answers
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML =
        (numCorrect == answers.length && numSelected == answers.length ? "Right" : "Try Again!");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aWsCu/

There are, of course, several ways to do this and this is by no means the best or cleanest... But, it's a start.

Comment: ah gotcha. thanks so much. but why does it say -  " â€‹ " in the browser?

Comment: Also what if I have 4 more variables ? like var answers1, answers2, answer3 and so on. And all contain different ids. Do i need to have 4 different loops . can i merge them into one ?

Comment: something like this would work ? http://pastebin.com/yymaDdYE . your help here is very much appreciated. thanks

Comment: Make sure you re-include the doctype and content type code at the top of the HTML page, should help. To reset it, you'll loop through all the TDs again and just set their classname back to `bgrd`.

Comment: Adding multiple sets of answers adds an additional layer of complexity. You have to loop through `answers` and each `answers1`, `answers1`, etc. The same code will not work if you change your array structure like that. Take a stab at getting it to work - you have all you need, just need to implement it.

Comment: Don't look at this if you want to get it yourself and haven't already but I was bored and got it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/fnkvH/1/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand you right. But try this code.

```
    <table id="myTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
            Select</td>
            <td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
            Select</td>
            <td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
            Select</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
            Select</td>
            <td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
            Select</td>
            <td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
            Select</td>

        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
            Select</td>
            <td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
            Select</td>
            <td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
            Select</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
            Select</td>
            <td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
            Select</td>
            <td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
            Select</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
            Select</td>
            <td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
            Select</td>
            <td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
            Select</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
            Select</td>
            <td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
            Select</td>
            <td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
            Select</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
            Select</td>
            <td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
            Select</td>
            <td class="bgrd" onclick="setColor(this)">
            Select</td>

        </tr>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var answerRow = 5;
        var noOfCols = 3;

        function setColor(what)
        {
            if(what.className == 'bgrd_selected')
            what.className = 'bgrd';
            else
            what.className = 'bgrd_selected';
            if(what.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('bgrd_selected').length == noOfCols)
            {
                if(document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tr')[answerRow].getElementsByClassName('bgrd_selected').length == noOfCols)
                    alert('You win');
                else
                {
                    alert('Try again');
                var arr = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('td') ;
                    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
                    {
                        arr[i].className="bgrd";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

</script>
<style type="text/css">
    table {
    width:400px;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border:1px solid #000;
    }
    table td {border:1px solid #000;}
    .bgrd {background-color:#CCCCCC;cursor:pointer;}
    .bgrd_selected {background-color:#FFCC00;cursor:pointer;}

</style>
```

Comment: Well its close. Please look here - http://pastebin.com/NU7hwD2V . Here if A1, B2 and C3 are selected it should say "Right" . if something else then it should say try again. Sorry but i thought i will make sense better above. and thanks

Comment: Need some time. On lunch. ;)

Comment: oh sure np. Thanks for your interest and helping me out here. Bon appétit

Comment: Guess you got the answer ;)